# Firebase Rule to read data on nested nodes for last 10 minutes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to implement a rule to read data for the last say 5 or 10 minutes. My database is like this:

[image: this].

I want to allow user to read messages of last 10 minutes but the rule is not working and i am not able to make it work I tried different rules like this.

```
"Messages": {
            "$messagekey": {
                "$key": {
                   ".read":"root.child('Users/Messages/'+$messagekey+'/'+$key+'/messageTime').val()> (now - 600000000)",                    }
                },
             ".write":"auth!=null"
            }
```

And this as well

```
"Messages": {
        "$messagekey": {
            "$key": {
                ".read": "data.child('messageTime').val() > (now - 600000)"
                    }
                },
                ".write": "auth!=null"
            }
```

Any help or suggestions please. 
Error message 
[image]

**Edit 2**
Using this rule I am still unable to make it work

```
{
        "rules": {
        "Messages": {
                    "$messagekey": {
                        "$key": {
                            ".read": "data.child('messageTime').val() > (now - 90000000)"
                        }
                    },
                    ".write": "auth!=null"
                }
      }
    }
```

and here is my data

```
 Users
        Messages
            WZTDdZslJrMFqgDLNWo4jXehsF02_nUVrJthSqHXH8Ur0stRz2tihxdg1
                -LPFPTBx7BA6urp-CSbZ
                        messageText: "Hello"
                        messageTime: 1540059028779
                        messageUser: "Joker's Grin"
                        messageUserId: "WZTDdZslJrMFqgDLNWo4jXehsF02"
                -LPFPUB5efDAIVu_AxP0
                        messageText: "how are you"
                        messageTime: 1540059028779
                        messageUser: "Crazy Eights"
                        messageUserId:"nUVrJthSqHXH8Ur0stRz2tihxdg1"
```

I am using two wildcards "**messagekey**" and "**key**" to reach messageId. Also tried these rules as well none of these work except read: true.

```
    ".read": "data.child('messageTime').val() >0"
    ".read": "data.child('messageTime').val() !==null"
    ".read": "data.exists()"
    ".read": "data.hasChild('MessageId')"
```

Here are the screenshots

[image]

Comment: That second snippet looks fine at first glance. What read operation did you run against it, and what was the error you got?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  here is the error message for second snippet
Simulation results
Type read
Location Users/Messages/abc123xyz/xyzabc123
Data null
Auth null
Read denied
Line 22 (/Users/Messages/abc123xyz/xyzabc123)
read: "data.child('messageTime').val() > (now - 600000)"

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem. I posted an answer below to show what I did. In the screenshot you posted (please always post textual content as actual text going forward), it looks like your `messageTime` is one digit shorter than the value I have used.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen still unable to make it work using two levels of wildcard. The only rule works is read:true. Please check edit.

Comment: For me it works equally well with nested children. See the updated screenshot. I don't see how yours is different unfortunately.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this is insane. I copied the rules from your updated screenshot, and still read is denied. :(

Answer (score 0):

I just added this value to a database of my own:

```
"52903949": {
  "messageTime": 1540054472392
}
```

Where `52903949` is the ID of your question, and `1540054472392` is the value returned by `Date.now()` when I added it.

Then I added these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "52903949": {
      ".read": "data.child('messageTime').val() > (now - 600000)"
    }
  }
}
```

And was able to access the data in the simulator with this result:

[image]

If I make the `600000` shorter, the read fails since that time has already expired.

---

**Updated screenshot with nested children**:

[image]